# how to hide Devexpress xtragrid auto emptybands

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In DevExpress XtraGrid an Empty Bands is displayed when one of its column position is set Fixed.
Here is the code:

```
   gridview1.DataSource = ds.Table[0];
   gridview1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
   gridview1.PopulateColumns();
   GridBand DateGridBand = new GridBand();
   DateGridBand.Columns.Add(gridview1.Columns["Date"]);
   gridview1.Bands.Add(DateGridBand).Fixed = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.FixedStyle.Left;

   GridBand gdBand = new GridBand();
   gdBand .Caption = "Details";
   gdBand .Columns.Add(gridview1.Columns["No"]);
   gdBand .Columns.Add(gridview1.Columns["Qty");
   gridview1.Bands.Add(gdBand );
```

how to avoid the Blank Bands.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: sry.! I can't since it requires 10 user reputation to post images.

Comment: Post a url to a screenshot...

Comment: pls check this link for SceenShot. http://i60.tinypic.com/1183gw7.jpg

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the header row.

```
// remove header row
GridView1.OptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders = False;
```

Knowing the two below will save you some time with further customization.

```
// remove side indicator
GridView1.OptionsView.ShowIndicator = False;

// remove group header
GridView1.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = False;
```